# jquery id attribute selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

i have a `<div id="mainDIV">` which contains  a `<table>` within which `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags are present.

Actually i am trying these selector

```
$("#mainDIV > tbody").on("click", function(){ 
    alert("test");
}
```

so that whenever we click inside the `<tbody>`, that alert should be displayed. But this is not working. Can anyone please suggest me solution for this.

---

I tried the below one but its not working...

```
$("#mainDIV  tbody").on("click", function(){ 
    alert("test");
}
```

This is my part of the code thats not working..

```
$("#ui-datepicker-div  tbody").on("click", function(){ 
                alert("test");
});
```

Comment: You forgot a parenthesis: last line: `});`. Use `$("#mainDIV  tbody")`.

Comment: That code works, you can see it in my fiddle below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use white space instead of `>`:

```
$("#mainDIV  tbody").on("click", function(){ 
    alert("test");
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9PAYH/8/)

Descendant Selector (`"ancestor descendant"`) [docs](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/):

> Description: Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor.

Child Selector (`"parent > child"`) [docs](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

> Description: Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mainDIV tbody').click(function() {
  alert("test");
});
```